# идентификация регулярного выражения по слову

Tags: python, html, регулярные-выражения, web-scraping, re

Как с помощу регулярных выражений получить цифры с тега если идентифицировать тег можно только по слову (Матчи,Забито Голов,Пропущено голов)?

дело в том что ето в большом теге div , и здесь только по слове внутри тега можно определить откуда брать цифры , `r"<tr>.*Матчи.*</tr>", r"<tr>.*Пропущено голов.*</tr>", r"<tr>.*Забито голов.*</tr>"` я так пробовал но не работает, мне нужно чтобы регулярка находила тег `<tr>` потом какието символы потом опредиляющее слово а потом тоже какието символы и закрыващий тег `</tr>`

```
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>Матчи </td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="red">14</td>
<td>Забито голов </td>
<td class="green">16</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="green">15</td>
<td>Пропущено голов </td>
<td class="red">26</td>
</tr>
```

вот код , я хочу с большого тега div найти определенные теги tr по ключевым словам а потом снова через регулярные выражения найти два числа , но регулярка неработает и просто выводит все числа с большого тега div.

```
class GameData:
    def __init__(self, html_text: str):
        self.__html_text = html_text.replace("\n", "")

    def get_games_quantity(self):
        pattern = r"<tr>.*Матчи.*</tr>"
        games_quantity_html_text = "".join(re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=self.__html_text))
        return re.findall(pattern=r"\d\d|\d", string=games_quantity_html_text)

    def get_goals_scored(self):
        pattern = r"<tr>.*Забито голов.*</tr>"
        games_quantity_html_text = "".join(re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=self.__html_text))
        return re.findall(pattern=r"\d\d|\d", string=games_quantity_html_text)

    def get_conceded_goals(self):
        pattern = r"<tr>.*Пропущено голов.*</tr>"
        games_quantity_html_text = "".join(re.findall(pattern=pattern, string=self.__html_text))
        return re.findall(pattern=r"\d\d|\d", string=games_quantity_html_text)

    def get_all_parametrs(self):
        return dict(
            games=self.get_games_quantity(),
            goals_scored=self.get_goals_scored(),
            conceded_goals=self.get_conceded_goals()
        )
```

Comment: не надо использовать регулярные выражения там где они не нужны. вы с помощью какого то языка пытаетесь это разобрать, или просто абстрактно прикрутить сюда регулярки в блокноте?

Comment: я пишу на python ,

Comment: возьмите какую нить библиотеку разбора HTML/XML. не надо разметку парсить с помощью регулярок. итерируйте строки, сверяйте значение ячейки

Comment: дело в том что теги одинаковые и отличие в них только по словам которые в них

Comment: r"<tr>.*Матчи.*</tr>" я так пробывал

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил для парсинга `html` таблиц использовать библиотеку `Pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

html = '''
<table>
<tr>
<td>10</td>
<td>Матчи </td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="red">14</td>
<td>Забито голов </td>
<td class="green">16</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="green">15</td>
<td>Пропущено голов </td>
<td class="red">26</td>
</tr>
</table>
'''

df = pd.read_html(html)[0]
```

Тогда в `df` получится такая табличка из 3-х строк и 3-х столбцов:

```
     0                1  2
0   10            Матчи 10
1   14     Забито голов 16
2   15  Пропущено голов 26
```

Доставать из неё данные можно, например, так:

```
goals1 = df.loc[df[1] == 'Забито голов', 0].values[0]
goals2 = df.loc[df[1] == 'Забито голов', 2].values[0]
print(goals1, goals2)
```

Вывод:

```
14 16
```

Comment: дело в том что ето в большом теге div , и здесь только по слове внутри тега можно определить откуда брать цифры , r"<tr>.*Матчи.*</tr>" я так пробовал но не работает, мне нужно чтобы регулярка находила тег <tr> потом какието символы потом опредиляющее слово а потом тоже какието символы и закрыващий тег </tr>